# Will disabling javascript be considered as cloaking by Google

Tags: seo, google-search, static-content, cloaking, angular.js

There is a site with dynamic content generation (angular). Google is not indexing it well. But it is indexed well with static pages (same content). Static pages are not fast because of page reloading each time. If I will render static pages only for Google (IPs,bots, google-analytics disabled) - will it be considered as cloaking (same content for human and the same DOM after load(just without script tags))?

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the JavaScript from the page based on IP, User Agent or any other method that detects Google, then yes its cloaking.

Treat Google like any other user. Angular websites are indexable just fine, its used by thousands of websites, I recommend that you dig deeper into your research on getting dynamic content seen.