# SEO | Cloaking | Is it safe to remove Third-party / Analytical scripts for crawlers/bots? Is this considered as cloaking?

Tags: web-crawlers, page-speed, optimization

Is it considered as cloaking if I remove third party scripts such as google tag manager, other analytics based scripts tags for crawlers/bots?

By removing these external javascripts I will surely have improved page performance(reduced page load time) for the Google Crawler and for effective SEO.

Though the question is related to [Will disabling javascript be considered as cloaking by Google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/115212/will-disabling-javascript-be-considered-as-cloaking-by-google)   But,  unlike there  I am trying to remove only Third party Scripts which are not vital for the site from crawlers perspective.

Can I do so? Please suggest.

Comment: Removing JavaScript for bots is not going to help SEO based on page performance.  When Google analyzes the performance of your page it uses "field data".   It gathers real world performance data from actual users and bases its performance evaluation for SEO on that rather than on the "lab data" that is generated by its crawler.  See [Will Google use field or lab data for ranking sites with core web vitals performance metrics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/132919/will-google-use-field-or-lab-data-for-ranking-sites-with-core-web-vitals-perform)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is cloaking. Googlebot should see the exact same page that users see. Google understands javascript and you are denying Google a chance to process the same to determine if the scripts modify the content or not.

While there can be variations based on geolocations or even mobile devices, any variation aimed specifically at Googlebot is risky. Below video by **Matt Cutts** should help.
Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHtnfOgp65Q

By the way, Google relies on real user experiences (CrUX) for page experience signals.

***Sidenote***: Google has just started a page-experience update by June 15, if that helps.
Ref: https://twitter.com/googlesearchc/status/1404886100087246848